# Add values to char in c?

Tags: c, char, unsigned-char

Hey guys so I have a `char` and I want to add some integer/double to it. The char must be a signed char, so I can't just make it an int.

```
char var = -55;
printf("Char is %d, add, char is now: %d\n", var, var+2);
```

That code works, but as soon as I want to add a fraction or something...

```
printf("Char is %d, add, char is now: %d\n", var, var+2/3*2);
```

It doesn't add at all. Any ideas why? Probably something to do with rounding and whatnot.

Thanks.

Comment: 2/3 equals zero.

Comment: Hmm? Should I be casting 2/3 to a double first?
EDIT - Haha, forgot basic BODMAS.. so yes 2/3 = 0 then multiplied by 2 = 0. -.-. Thanks!

Comment: Declare `var` as `signed char` explicitly, or you're risking to end up using `unsigned char` when you use a different compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
printf("Char is %d, add, char is now: %d\n", var, (int)( var+(2/(double)3)*2 ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
printf("Char is %d, add, char is now: %d\n", var, (int)(var+2/3.0*2));
```